# Make AJAX pages with dynamically loaded data crawlable

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, google-crawlers

Last year, Google announced that it deprecated its previous Ajax Crawling proposal and stated:

> Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your
>   JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and
>   understand your web pages like modern browsers.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Indeed, Google today crawls content inserted by JS, with a few notable exceptions. For example:

> If you have to hit any third-party services/APIs before the user
>   interface can provide any value to the end user.

https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/issues/819#issuecomment-223697246

**Are there any client-side rendering methods to allow crawling content that was retrieved after "hitting a third-party service/API"?**
(For example by simulating synchronous loading, deferring rendering etc. etc.)

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to bypass this limitation on client-side is to use JSONP when available. I replied to your question but I was immediately downvoted...